# GDAL polygonize command line and python

Tags: python, gdal

I have been using `gdal` from the command line to convert an `asc` file to a `GeoJSON` output. I can do this successfully:

`gdal_polygonize.py input.asc -f "GeoJSON" output.json`

Now I wish to use Python and follow this process for a range of files.

```
import gdal
import glob
for file in glob.glob("dir/*.asc"):
    new_name = file[:-4] + ".json"
    gdal.Polygonize(file, "-f", "GeoJSON", new_name)
```

Hpwever, for exactly the same file I get the following error `TypeError: in method 'Polygonize', argument 1 of type 'GDALRasterBandShadow *'`

Why does the command line version work and the python version not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to find what is wrong with your call to gdal.Polygonize is to investigate the documentation for that function. You can find it [here](https://gdal.org/api/gdal_alg.html) by going through the C algorithms API. Admittedly, GDAL's documentation isn't the most coherent and easy to access. This is doubly true for the conversion of the C API to Python.

### GDALPolygonize

```
GDALPolygonize  (GDALRasterBandH    hSrcBand,
                 GDALRasterBandH    hMaskBand,
                 OGRLayerH          hOutLayer,
                 int                iPixValField,
                 char **            papszOptions,
                 GDALProgressFunc   pfnProgress,
                 void *             pProgressArg 
                )
```

You can see that the first two arguments are RasterBand types. The output type is an OGRLayer, and there are other (in this case unnecessary) options.

To use `gdal.Polygonize()` you will need to open your input file with gdal, get a raster band, and pass that into the function. Similarly, you will need to create a new geojson vector file, and pass its layer into the function.

### Using `subprocess`

As an alternative, you could employ python's `subprocess` module to call the same command-line program that you already know.

```
import subprocess
import glob
import os

for f in glob.glob("dir/*.asc"): # don't override python's file variable
    out_file = f[:-4] + ".json"
    in_file = os.path.join("dir", f) # need the full path of the input
    cmdline = ['gdal_polygonize.py', in_file, ,"-f", "GeoJSON", out_file]
    subprocess.call(cmdline)
```