How to run gdal_polygonize.py?
This is my first question in the forum, so please apologize if I'm not following some forum etiquette rules.
I'm trying to run gdal_polygonize.py to polygonize a raster file with this code,
# 4- CONVERT RASTER DATA TO VECTOR
input_layer = raster.tif
output = shapefile.shp

subprocess.call('"C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\gdal\\share\\bash-completion\\completions\\gdal_polygonize.py" %s -f "ESRI Shapefile" %s' %(input_layer, output),shell=True)

The input_layer is already where the code is looking for it. But I'm not understanding the reason for that gdal_polygonize.py is not generating the output shapefile. There's no error message indicating something wrong when running subprocess.call(...).
I tried to address the issue with solutions provided in this entry, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40157820/17237490, but I was unsuccessful.
Any help is much appreciated!

The linked question also indicates how you can use the polygonize function by importing gdal and then running gdal.Polygonize() instead of a subprocess, have you tried that?

I’m not familiar with how GDAL gets installed on Windows, but having a Python program installed under bash_completion\completions seems really strange. Are you sure you are running the right thing?

Can you directly run a .py file as the first parameter in the command line? that's a little weird. Generally we import functions or classes from other .py files and run it.

@ChuangMen Not sure how these things work on Windows, but on a Un*x system, if the file has an appropriate "shebang line" (and gdal_polygonize, properly installed, has), then yes, you can.

Hi everyone, thank you for your comments! I'm cleaning up the code to facilitate understanding. I installed GDAL for the first time two days ago using the OSGEoW4 network installer (selecting Express Install). The only place where I find gdal_polygonize.py is the folder you're seeing in subprocess.call(...).

Well, I installed GDAL using the Generic installer for the GDAL core components from  https://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1928-x64-gdal-3-9-1-mapserver-8-2-0.zip. Now, I see C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal_polygonize.py but the subprocess isn't running the function.

I get this warning in a separate window:
#!C:\Python\Python310\python.exe
import sys
from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
# import osgeo_utils.gdal_polygonize as a convenience to use as a script
from osgeo_utils.gdal_polygonize import *  # noqa
from osgeo_utils.gdal_polygonize import main, from what I understand I have to use the function by running gdal.Polygonize.

Typically it is more convenient and easier to debug to use a python API if available.
Especially for this example, the standard GDAL python API isn't the most convenient, but the following snippet shows how you can do it that way:
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

gdal.UseExceptions()

src = r"C:\Temp\polygon_parcel\polygon-parcel.tif"
output = r"C:\Temp\polygon_parcel\polygon-parcel_polygonized.shp"

# Open input
src_ds = gdal.Open(src)
srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# Create output shapefile
output_ds = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile").CreateDataSource(output)
srs = src_ds.GetSpatialRef()
output_layer = output_ds.CreateLayer("output_layer", geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon, srs=srs)
data_type = ogr.OFTInteger
if srcband.DataType in (gdal.GDT_Int64, gdal.GDT_UInt64):
    data_type = ogr.OFTInteger64
fd = ogr.FieldDefn("DN", data_type)
output_layer.CreateField(fd)

# Polygonize
gdal.Polygonize(srcBand=srcband, maskBand=None, outLayer=output_layer, iPixValField=0)


Typically it is more convenient and easier to debug to use a python API if available.
GDAL has its own python API, but there are some other, more "Pythonic" python API's to GDAL functionalities. For this example an option is to use rasterio for polygonizing the image and geopandas to write the polygons to a shapefile:
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio
from rasterio import features

src = r"C:\Temp\polygon_parcel\polygon-parcel.tif"
output = r"C:\Temp\polygon_parcel\polygon-parcel_polygonized_rio.shp"

result = []
with rasterio.open(src) as srcfile:
    # Vectorize.
    ds_features = features.dataset_features(srcfile, bidx=1, geographic=False)
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(ds_features, crs=srcfile.crs)

gdf.to_file(output)

